# Zend_Translate : How can be done with zend framework translation that will translate each expression according his html id?

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, translation, zend-translate

I beginner in zend framework and its a bit hard for me to understand zend_translate how its works.

**My Main Question:**
How can be done with zend framework translation that will translate each expression according his html id and how non programmer translator can see word location in web browser for translate each expression according his content.

**My Sub Questions:**

1.How to update additional fields of csv file that holds translation of website?**

2.webpage original word url can not be seen in browser because he sub view that appear in parent form etc

**If i have mistakes or you have better solution etc.. please write it.**

---

**My targets and partly solutions:**

1.Give to non programmer making translation - I choose **csv** file.

2.Translate separately each word/expression according her appearance context on page and element id- I add columns **webpage url** and **html id** to csv file.
(But I have problem that sometimes webpage url can not be seen in browser because he sub view that appear in parent form etc..)

Example1:

view.phtml

```
........<div id="view-error"><?php translate("error was produced by empty") ?></div>....
......<div id="view-user-firstname"><?php translate("First Name") ?></div>....
```

**My Implementation plan without zend code (I don't know how to do that with zend):**

**csv files columns names:**

1.**original word** - original word that  taking from the page to translate

```
<?php echo translate($original_word) ?>
```

2.**spain/sweden translation** - translation of original word

3.**webpage url**- webpage link to word translation location 
(For translator important to know the location of word to check in which context she used)

4.**html id** - the id of html div/span/etc.. of translated word

||**original word** || **spain translation** ||**sweden translation** || **webpage url** || **html id** ||

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A regular practice is to have a separate file for each context.

For example each module can have its own translation source file

if you have modules like

modules/user

modules/categories

modules/products

modules/checkout

then you can create appropriate file for each module with all the phrases needs to be translated.

user.cvs

categories.cvs

products.cvs

checkout.cvs

It is not recommended to use URL because in most cases same phrases are used on many pages inside one specific module. So its better to provide a set of screenshots for translator of each page from the specific module.